# How can i make my first <LI> Tag to be colored when it dynamically changes in sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if my title is really difficult to understand.

I am trying to make my Listview to be drag and drop, but I want my first `<li>` tag to be colored always after it has been dragged and droped, how can I implement that?

here is my existing code:

```
    $("li").first().css( "background-color", "#101F30" );
    $("li").first().css( "color", "#fff" );

// For default timezone listview
    $(function() {
        $("#allTimezoneFacets, #userTimezoneFacets").sortable({
                connectWith: "ul",
                placeholder: "placeholder",
                delay: 150
            })
            .disableSelection()
            .click(function(e) {
                var item = e.target;
                console.log(item);
            });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper_timezone">
                    <ul id="allTimezoneFacets" class="facet-list">
                     <li class="facet">
                         <p class="timezone_right" id="timezone_tn_date"></p>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial">TN</h2>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial timezone_right timezone_right_padding" id="timezone_tn_time"></h2>
                         <p class="timezone_padding">Tennessee</p>
                     </li>
                     <li class="facet">
                         <p class="timezone_right" id="timezone_ny_date"></p>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial">NY</h2>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial timezone_right timezone_right_padding" id="timezone_ny_time"></h2>
                         <p class="timezone_padding">New York</p>
                     </li>
                     <li class="facet">
                         <p class="timezone_right timezone_ph_date" id="timezone_ph_date"></p>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial">PH</h2>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial timezone_right timezone_right_padding timezone_ph_time" id="timezone_ph_time">9:01:43 AM</h2>
                         <p class="timezone_padding">Philippines</p>
                     </li>
                     <li class="facet">
                         <p class="timezone_right" id="timezone_ca_date"></p>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial">CA</h2>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial timezone_right timezone_right_padding" id="timezone_ca_time"></h2>
                         <p class="timezone_padding">California</p>
                     </li>
                     <li class="facet">
                         <p class="timezone_right timezone_id_date">Friday, January 31, 2020</p>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial">ID (MT)</h2>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial timezone_right timezone_right_padding timezone_id_time">3:01:43 PM</h2>
                         <p class="timezone_padding">Idaho-Mountain</p>
                     </li>
                     <li class="facet">
                         <p class="timezone_right" id="timezone_ak_date"></p>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial">AK</h2>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial timezone_right timezone_right_padding" id="timezone_ak_time"></h2>
                         <p class="timezone_padding">Alaska</p>
                     </li>
                     <li class="facet">
                         <p class="timezone_right" id="timezone_pr_date">Friday, January 31, 2020</p>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial">PR</h2>
                         <h2 class="timezone_initial timezone_right timezone_right_padding" id="timezone_pr_time">9:01:43 PM</h2>
                         <p class="timezone_padding">Puerto Rico</p>
                     </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

here is what I currently have.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/rmallari/gr06mxow/8/
```

Any help would be really appreciated, sorry if my english is poor.

Comment: You can just use CSS: `.facet-list li:first-child{ ... }`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz omg. hhuhuhuh why i didn't thought this :(, thank you very much sir. can you your answer from it? so that i can check it.

Comment: Glad to help :) Posted as an answer as you asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `:first-child` CSS selector to style the first `li` item

```
.facet-list li:first-child{
   background-color: "#101F30;
   color: "#fff";
}
```